# Selecting the camera with Numberpad 0 brings up a strange box?

Tags: camera

Clearly Im new.  I thought I had my life together on blender and was ready to do something and then i realized that i still apparently dont know how to control the camera or at least fix what I am 100% certain I broke when my cat walked across my keyboard.... if i had a cat... anyway, When I push 0, the camera looks at this box.  I cant get to give me the camera view.   what did i do? [image]

heres a link to my blender project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hd5Qthfw8sKqXx7gEYN8-eMpIUq-qY7i/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, by "Camera is looking at this box" - the box is the camera view - just zoomed out and offset because it is "locked" in it's viewing position. If you want to adjust your view relative to the camera view, you have
to disable "Lock Camera to View":

[image: Lock]